# How to access to object property inside jQuery event function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for my english. Here is example code:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function MyNewClass(){
  this.$my_new_button = $('<button>Button</button>');
  this.my_value = 5;

  this.init = function (){
    $('body').append(this.$my_new_button);
    this.$my_new_button.click(
      function (){
        // Its always alerts "undefined"
        alert(this.my_value);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

How can i access objects `my_value` property inside jQuery click event function?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following

```
function MyNewClass(){
    this.$my_new_button = $('<button>Button</button>');
    this.my_value = 5;
    var self = this; //add in a reference to this
    this.init = function (){
        $('body').append(this.$my_new_button);
        this.$my_new_button.click(
            function (){
                //This will now alert 5.
                alert(self.my_value);
            }
        );
    };
}
```

This is a small pattern in javascript (although the name eludes me). It allows you to access top level members of a function within an inner function. In a nested function you can't use "this" to refer to top level members as it will only refer to the function you are within. hence the need to declare the top level functions "this" value into its own variable (called self in this case).

Answer (score 4):

Jquery has a method for that, [jQuery.proxy( function, context )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

```
function MyNewClass(){ 
  this.$my_new_button = $('<button>Button</button>');
  this.my_value = 5;

  this.init = function (){
    $('body').append(this.$my_new_button);
    this.$my_new_button.click(
      $.proxy(function (){
        // Its always alerts "undefined"
        alert(this.my_value);
      },this)
    )
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fv39h/)